# Regular expression explanation required

Tags: regex

I came across this regular expression which is used to check for alphabetic strings. Can anyone explain how it works to me?

```
/^\pL++$/uD
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\pL+` (sometimes written as `\p{L}`) matches one or more Unicode letter(s). I prefer `\p{L}` to `\pL` because there are other Unicode properties like `\p{Lu}` (uppercase letter) that only work with the braces; `\pLu` would mean "a Unicode letter followed by the letter `u`").

The additional `+` makes the quantifier possessive, meaning that it will never relinquish any characters it has matched, even if that means an overall match will fail. In the example regex, this is unnecessary and can be omitted.

`^` and `$` anchor the match at the start and end of the string, ensuring that the entire string has to consist of letters. Without them, the regex would also match a substring surrounded by non-letters.

The entire regex is delimited by slashes (`/`). After the trailing slash, [PHP regex options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) follow. `u` is the Unicode option (necessary to handle the Unicode property).  `D` ensures that the `$` only matches at the very end of the string (otherwise it would also match right before the final newline in a string if that string ends in a newline).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like PCRE flavor.

According to [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/):

```
Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
A character with the Unicode property “letter” (any kind of letter from any language) «\pL++»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, without giving back (possessive) «++»
Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
```

Comment: @Tim, yes the forward slash is just a delimiter, I think. Other than that, i think the others make sense. LEt me know if I'm wrong?

Comment: @Tim - You're correct; I wasn't paying attention. I assumed (incorrectly) that the OP posted the RegEx without surrounding code. Corrected my answer; +1 to yours.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like Unicode processing.. I found a neat article here that seems to explain \pL the rest are anchors and repetition characters.. which are also explained on this site:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Enjoy

Comment: I found this site. Do the Curly braces make a difference or are they jsut optional? Can you let me know what a '++' is there for?

Comment: The {} are optional ONLY in certain implementations of the regular expressions (PHP, PERL and Java I think were the three listed)